# How to grab an XML element and store it? Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, parsing, token

I am trying to grab a token from a website. Upon successful authentication, an XML document would be displayed.

I created a connection as shown below:

```
NSString *strURLQueryString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?username=%@&password=%@", kURL_LOGIN, nameString, passwordString];
    NSURLRequest *theRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURLQueryString]
                                                cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                            timeoutInterval:60.0];
```

In order to display the output, I used this:

```
unsigned char byteBuffer[[receivedData length]];
[receivedData getBytes:byteBuffer];
NSLog(@"Output: %s", (char *)byteBuffer);
```

So some of the output of the returned document is as shown below:

```
    <status>0</status><reason>User fetched.</reason><token>9cb7396dccabe68c067521db219afb83</token>
```

I have read many XML parsing implementation but I just could not implement it as it does not fulfil my need, and I just could not understand the complexity of its explanation.

Would appreciate if anyone could give me a good advice on how to go about.

Comment: Use NSXMLParser. its easy to understand. it has some delegates methods which is quite easy. so try that.

Comment: Use NSXMLParser to parse it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (XMLParserViewController *) initXMLParser {


    appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    return self;
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName
    attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict 
{

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Books"]) {
        appDelegate.books = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Book"])
    {

        aBook = [[Books alloc] init];

    }

    NSLog(@"Processing Element: %@", elementName);
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {

    if(!currentElementValue)
        currentElementValue = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:string];
    else
        [currentElementValue appendString:string];

    NSLog(@"Processing Value: %@", currentElementValue);

}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Books"])
        return;

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Book"])
    {
       [appDelegate.books addObject:aBook];        
          aBook = nil;
    }
    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"name"])
    {
        aBook.name=currentElementValue;
    }
    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"address"])
    {
        aBook.address=currentElementValue;
    }
    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"country"])
    {
        aBook.country=currentElementValue;
    }        

    currentElementValue = nil;


    NSLog(@"%@",aBook.name);
    NSLog(@"%@",aBook.address);
    NSLog(@"%@",aBook.country);
}
```

Try this ,, I hope this works....

Answer (score 0):

The relevant NSXMLParserDelegate methods:

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName //etc 
{ _inToken = [elementName isEqualToString:@"token"]; }

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName  //etc
{ _inToken = NO; }

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {
  if (_inToken) {
      _token = string;
      [parser abortParsing];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use XML parser.
It is easy to use, go all below steps to get best result:

Create XMLParser class subclasses from NSXMLParser, so you have a NSXMLParser.h and NSXMLParser.m class

your .h class must be like this:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface XMLParser : NSXMLParser <NSXMLParserDelegate>{

    NSUInteger parsedCounter;
    BOOL accumulatingParsedCharacterData;
    BOOL didAbortParsing;
}
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableString *currentParsedCharacterData;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *currentParsedCharacterArray;
@end
```

And .m class :

```
#import "XMLParser.h"

@implementation XMLParser

#pragma mark Parser constants

// Limit the number of parsed data to 100.
static const NSUInteger kMaximumNumberOfFilesToParse = 100;

static NSUInteger const kSizeOfFileBatch = 10;

// Reduce potential parsing errors by using string constants declared in a single place.
static NSString * const kEntryElementName = @"dlResult";
static NSString * const kStringElementName = @"string";


#pragma mark NSXMLParser delegate methods

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

//    NSLog(@"didStart");
    // If the number of parsed earthquakes is greater than kMaximumNumberOfEarthquakesToParse, abort the parse.
    if (parsedCounter >= kMaximumNumberOfFilesToParse) {
        // Use the flag didAbortParsing to distinguish between this deliberate stop and other parser errors.
        didAbortParsing = YES;
        [self abortParsing];
    }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:kEntryElementName]) {
        _currentParsedCharacterArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    } else if ([elementName isEqualToString:kStringElementName]) {

        accumulatingParsedCharacterData = YES;
        _currentParsedCharacterData = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
    }
}

// return string between tags
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {
//    NSLog(@"foundCh");
    if (accumulatingParsedCharacterData) {
        // If the current element is one whose content we care about, append 'string'
        // to the property that holds the content of the current element.
        [_currentParsedCharacterData appendString:string];
        NSLog(@"currentParsedCharacterData:%@",_currentParsedCharacterData);
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {
//    NSLog(@"didEnd");

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:kStringElementName]) {
        [_currentParsedCharacterArray addObject:_currentParsedCharacterData];

    }
    accumulatingParsedCharacterData = NO;
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser parseErrorOccurred:(NSError *)parseError {
       if (didAbortParsing == NO) {
        // Pass the error to the main thread for handling.
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(handleError:) withObject:parseError waitUntilDone:NO];
    }
}

@end
```

In .m class there are two const string:

```
static NSString * const kEntryElementName = @"dlResult";
static NSString * const kStringElementName = @"string";
```

those are string tags,the tags that you should implement are "status", "reason" "token"

from connection class, send data connection to XMLParser class like below:

```
@autoreleasepool {

    // It's also possible to have NSXMLParser download the data, by passing it a URL, but this is not desirable
    // because it gives less control over the network, particularly in responding to connection errors.
    //
        XMLParser *parser = [[XMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];

        parser.currentParsedCharacterArray = [NSMutableArray array];
        parser.currentParsedCharacterData = [NSMutableString string];
        [parser setDelegate:parser];

        [parser parse];

        // depending on the total number of earthquakes parsed, the last batch might not have been a "full" batch, and thus
        // not been part of the regular batch transfer. So, we check the count of the array and, if necessary, send it to the main thread.

        if ([parser.currentParsedCharacterArray count] > 0) {
            // send parsed data to another class or ...
            // parser.currentParsedCharacterArray is parsed data
        }
        parser.currentParsedCharacterArray = nil;
        parser.currentParsedCharacterData = nil;
    }
```

if you have any question, ask me!

Comment: Hi, thank you for the suggestion. Just to let you know, I just started reading about objective -c about 3 days ago. As such, I apologise if my question(s) sounds dumb. Where do I specify "token"? And, how do I actually implement it in the main file. I have read the NSXML documentation but I still do not really understand.

Comment: oh and I don't understand the 2 lines below: "elementName isEqualToString:kEntryElementName" and "[elementName isEqualToString:kStringElementName]". Why are they looking for "dlResult" and "string"?

Comment: It is OK! I know coding with Objective-c is not easy in the first month!

Comment: You can implement the XML Parser in the main class, but I think it is not easy to you! Try to create a new class by going to File-> New -> File, then under ios section select Cocoa Touch, select Objective-C class! click on the Next and fill the subclass by "NSXMLParser" and  Class by "XMLParser", click next. Now you create this class! Don't forgot to add header of this class on your main class.

Comment: The XML is a tag language,and data are between tags, such as <name>fa</name>, <family>shapouri</family>, <country>Iran</country>, <language>Persian</language>, so to parse the data between this tags you should define constant from tags 
static NSString * const kStringElementName = @"name";
static NSString * const kStringElementFamily = @"family";
static NSString * const kStringElementCountry = @"country";
static NSString * const kStringElementLanguage = @"language";
and use them in parser:didEndElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName: method to assign _currentParsedCharacterData to correct tag!